# A noun for a clumsy lady

Tags: одним-словом

Is there any Russian noun that would describe a clumsy and awkward girl?

Comment: To me, asking for a translation is posting something in one language and asking to have it rewritten in another. Here the poster is asking users to search their lexicons for any words that may refer to the item described - not quite the same thing. I, for one, found the answers provided extremely interesting as a Russian learner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**кутАфья**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/847102) - an awkwardly dressed woman (personally have never heard it or used myself, seems outdated)

[**гусЫня**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8F)- original meaning is *a female geese*  (not very frequent and pretty offensive)

[**растЯпа**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1005370) - this is a unisex term for a clumsy person who often drops or misses things

[**растЫка**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/235563/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0) - another unisex term, same as **растяпа** (pretty recent in general use, although i myself have never used it or heard much, [seems borrowed from regional vernacular](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%90%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0))

[**копУха**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0) - unisex, a sluggish person, whom everything takes lots of time to accomplish (from *копаться*)

[**недотёпа**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BF%D0%B0) - unisex, a person who fails at practical tasks (its Ukrainian cognate *до**тЭп**ный* means *clever*, *witty* so due to the negating prefix *недо-* which means *"short of, under"* it has a second meaning *dimwit* mentioned in the Wiktionary, and its root might be related to the root of *рас-**тяп**а*)

Comment: honestly, none of this is immediately recognizable as a word for clumsy lady.
those are exactly those kind of words Slavic professors from western universities are putting into their dictionaries. down-voting this.

Comment: it seems you need to chill as your overreaction makes you overstep your duties as a moderator which i start to think is not befitting yourself

Comment: as a member of community I have right to down-vote and it's actually very welcome to explain yourself whenever you down-voting. all further discussion on whether I should or shouldn't step off as a moderator can be addressed somewhere else but definitely this post is not the place.

Comment: ok, i will send a letter to the Kremlin... downvoting my responses is totally OK, but you've downvoted two in one topic + locked the latter, that's too much activity which betrays some kind of frenzy... and that **растяпа** is not immediately recognizable, you must be kidding

Comment: I've locked it because "Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated". I think you can not argue that there's no a slightest hint of research effort indicated.  The author haven't even bothered to list english counterparts, for instance. Your answers are still valid and valuable though. That's the reason it's locked but hardly would be deleted.

Comment: "and that растяпа is not immediately recognizable, you must be kidding " - thus you sort of acknowledge that the rest of the words are quite exotic ))

Comment: i made no secret that they were by supplying them with comments... which is more nuanced than your sweeping generalization with the word 'none'... the OP asked for words in general, not modern or current words, so your problem with the answers is concocted and imaginary

Answer (score 7):

[Курица](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmBkGRGQSJw) :)

Often used like this:

- Какая же ты курица!

Answer (score 4):

**Кулёма** - это обычно неумелая, неловкая, неуклюжая женщина или девочка, позже стало употребляться и по отношению к мужчине, чтобы подчеркнуть отсутствие мужских навыков и характера.http://fb.ru/article/330487/chto-znachit-kulema-znachenie-slova

Comment: I have never heard this word before. Have you?

Comment: down-voting this as well. Come on people, unless it asked explicitly we should try to teach modern Russian which is de-facto used. Virtually no one uses this words nowadays (if it ever was widely recognized).

Comment: Yes, my grandma used to call my dad "Коля-кулёма" :)

Comment: my grandma did as well, regionally and locally i believe it still might be in use